# IE displays div not the right size

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Why this div in IE displays as 30 pixels(measure with Photoshop)
In all other browsers it displays correctly 29 pixels

```
<div style="width:29px;height:18px;background-color:Black;"></div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nRnwM/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer renders element’s width incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685329/internet-explorer-renders-elements-width-incorrectly)

Answer (score 0):

add `display: block;` to your styles, and then refresh... it may do the trick

Comment: yes div is a block by default, but i have a suspicion that IE isn't rendering it as one. what is your doctype?...